# Dates and Timezones in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp

I am currently reading dates in JSON format as follows:

```
"dates": {
    "startdate": "2017-08-29T22:00:00.000UTC";
}
```

And in my application, I set the JsonFormat as follows to be able to read it correctly:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'UTC'")
private Date startdate;
```

But UTC isn't the TimeZone I want to work with, what should I change 'UTC' into to be able to read my dateTime in the Europe/Paris zone?

Comment: Do you want `2017-08-29T22:00` in Paris timezone, or `2017-08-29T22:00UTC` converted to Paris (which will be `2017-08-30T00:00+02:00`)? And are you using jackson? Or some other library? (it might be relevant to the solution) - BTW, you can't just ignore UTC, it's relevant to the `Date` object (otherwise you can get different results, depending on what you do after ignoring it).

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but did you try either `Z` or `z`, which both just mean time zone?  One of those will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Alter the input to comply with the ISO 8601 standard. The `Z` is short for Zulu and means UTC.

```
String input =  "2017-08-29T22:00:00.000UTC".replace( "UTC" , "Z" ) ;
```

Parse as an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Adjust into your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Avoid the `Date` class as that troublesome class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.